# Node JS + AngularJS projects merge issue

Tags: angularjs, node.js

Hello I am merging two of my projects you can say CMS and web into a single project.

Both projects have different controllers and CSS. I have created separate folders for admin and web.

But need to load controllers on the basis of path like /admin/home or /web/home. I am unable to found any solution.

I tried to do that according to the state name, but with that my controllers are not loading.

Comment: Can you provide a more graphic question, because this is not really clear to me and I think to not a lot of other people.

Comment: Create separate modules for each project.
Example:-cmsModule,webModule
Use one module as a root module and then inject other Module into that. You will be able to load controllers of both module 
Thanks